# how to copy selected text using python

Tags: python, keyboard, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

I am writing a program in python, the essence of which is that it selects text with the mouse moving along the coordinates and copies it, I used both pag and keyboard for copying, nothing helped in the end, what I have in the clipboard is transmitted to the console, and instead of the selection it decreases sound volume, tried to set time.sleeps but they also do not help the test is carried out on windows 11 and windows 10

```
def mouse_movier_to_text_and_copy(filtered_data, x, y):
        all_text = []
        for i in filtered_data:
            mouse.move(x, y, absolute=True)
            mouse.move(*i, absolute=False)
            mouse.double_click("left")
            mouse.click("left")
            keyboard.press_and_release("ctrl+a")
            keyboard.press_and_release("ctrl+c")
            # pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "A")
            # pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "c")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            clipboard_content = pyperclip.paste()
            if clipboard_content not in all_text:
                all_text.append(clipboard_content)
    
        return all_text
`
# For test
import mouse
import keyboard
import pyautogui
mouse.move(x,y)
#your coordinates
mouse.click("left")
mouse.doubleclick("left")
keyboard.press_and_release("ctrl+a")         
keyboard.press_and_release("ctrl+c")
# pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "A")
# pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "c")
time.sleep(0.1)
clipboard_content = pyperclip.paste()
    if clipboard_content not in all_text:
        all_text.append(clipboard_content)
print(all_text)
```

Comment: If you're still unable to find the problem, I'd suggest updating the question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, please mention the library you use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.